# How to test a function that has .base() call

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I would like to do a unit test to a function that has a call to the base class inside it implementation (using .base() )

I cannot use Mocking as this is inheritance we dealing with, so I don't get the object in my constructor.

Example code:

```
protected override BuyerDeal Map(BuyerDealDTO buyerDealDTO, BuyerDeal buyerDealEntity)
{            
    buyerDealEntity.prop1 = buyerDealDTO.prop2;
    base.Map(buyerDealDTO, buyerDealEntity);
    return buyerDealEntity;
}
```

I would like to test this function but I don't want this:

```
base.Map(buyerDealDTO, buyerDealEntity);
```

to occur, as I test the base by itself.

Yet i do want to test ( Verify ) the call, and solely, the call to the base .

btw, the base class is **abstract**.

The problem is that if there is few classes that inherit from that base class this will result in testing the base class more than once .

Comment: So, you want to *change* the *behaviour* of the code when you're testing it? Why do you want to avoid the `base` call, if it's part of the normal behaviour for the class?

Comment: because i'm testing this current mapper not the base mapper so i don't want it to call the base Mapper as for the base mapper i have another unit test . and i dont want to supply properties of the base mapper just so the code will run without any problem, this is wrong..

Comment: @jony89 The base method call is *part of* the "current" mapper. The test is meaningless without it.

Comment: imaging that i have ten classes that inherit from that base class, if i go as you said that means that i would test my base class 10 times .

Comment: sorry, but your base class is not a dependency, so you cannot, and should not, skip it

Comment: well i dont agree with you, like as i said, this requires to test the mapping of the base class more than once(as i have many classes that inehrit from this base class) which is not necessary and wrong . Also Im pretty sure that there is a way to skip it ( maybe using fakes.. )

Comment: You're not testing the base class more than once - you're testing (in part) how the *current* class *uses* the base class.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't think so, if i Verify the call to the base class (and maybe the number of calls also) it should be enough .

Comment: Well then, you're basically asking for a means to change this class's base class at runtime - which isn't possible - and suggests that this maybe shouldn't have been modelled as inheritance in the first place.

Comment: @jony89: I agree with Damien_The_Unbeliever. That's exactly what I suggested in my answer. When something seems 'hard to test', it usually means that you have an underlying design smell. From my point of view, the coupling of derived classes to this protected method is unnecessary and should be replaced with an injectable dependency, which you can mock. It will make your testing life much easier once you get the hang of it.

Comment: @EagleBeak you are not familiar with the whole project, the coupling is necessary. In addition - its not hard to test it ( i can easily giev the properties of the base class and not Assert them in my test ) The whole point is how to do it right .

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing much about your mapper there might be several ways to do that:

Split your code and the map code into separate methods, e.g:

```
protected override BuyerDeal Map(BuyerDealDTO buyerDealDTO, BuyerDeal buyerDealEntity)
{            
    ExtraLogic(...);
    base.Map(buyerDealDTO, buyerDealEntity);
    return buyerDealEntity;
}

protected void ExtraLogic(...)
{
    buyerDealEntity.prop1 = buyerDealDTO.prop2;
}
```

then you can test ExtraLogic. This might not work for all code as calling base may be required as a dependency, which changes the flow, as stated by comments. 
I generally would not recommend that.

Or don't inherit from the base class. Inherit from the `Interface` and mock your abstract class then. Favour composition over inheritance (FCoI).
This allows you to inject the base class and test your code only.
Might not work if no interface is defined (which is bad anyway) or if the framework uses the abstract class explicitly.

Comment: The first solution is nice, thought the ExtraLogic then can't be protected and then we will get an exposed method (which we dont want to expose.. ) the second solution is wrong as i have implementation in my base class so it cannot be replaced with interface . (or you talking about containing an instance of the base class which is not what i want either )

Comment: Basically yes. The second solution implies that you have no abstract class that you can inject into your own class providing methods like `Map(..,..);`

Comment: @jony89 Inheritance tightly couples one class ("derived") to another ("base"). If an `Apple` is a `Fruit`, then that's it; nothing can change that. Since your test wants to replace the base class with something else, it strongly implies that your SUT probably *isn't* a sub-type of that base class.

Answer (score 1):

I see three approaches:

1. Try to **ignore the base class** in derived classes' tests. Problem here is that your tests are incomplete, because you never test the interaction of derived classes' code with the base class.
2. **Parallel inheritance hierarchies** for test fixtures, i.e. an abstract fixture for the base class, which is inherited by all fixtures for derived classes. This helps to remove duplication and tests the above mentioned interaction, but makes the fixtures hard to understand.
3. **Follow [Composition over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)** whenever possible. No base classes, no headaches.

I would suggest to follow the third one, especially as it looks as if the mapping between buyer deals might be considered a separate responsibility anyway.

**Bottom line**: Just create a `BuyerDealMapper`, test that, and mock it when you test the other classes.

Comment: If you talking about the base class then its abstract, the base class is `DealMapper`

Comment: @jony89: I don't understand. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @EagleBeak You can lead a horse to water but you can't make him drink

Comment: @EagleBeak : i was talking about your Bottom line. i cannot mock it as this is abstract and used with .base(). i don't want to change this behaviour .

Comment: @Infer-On : comparing me to horse is very nice of you, maybe it says something about you..

Answer (score 0):

When unit testing, you are in fact testing that the *code under test* gives the correct output for the corresponding input.

This input may come in the form of dependencies, such as method parameters, data read from the file system or from a network source.

The output may come in the form of a value returned from the method, data written to the file system or properties passed into another class for instance.

As long as your input produces the expected output, **within reason, anything else that happens in that *code under test* does not matter.**

In your posted code, your unit test should not care whether or not the call to `base.Map(buyerDealDTO, buyerDealEntity);` is made or not - just that the *code under test* gives the expected output.

If perhaps your base class itself requires dependencies, such as file system writes or network reads etc..., these can be mocked in your test start up routines.

If you are worried that you are **testing the base class multiple times, this is actually a very good thing!** The more times code is tested, the more conditions and situations a piece of code sees, the more thorough, the more bullet-proof that piece of code will be. Your unit test should help guarantee that your base class code and cope with your inherited classes use of it.

For instance, how will your method cope if the base class throws an exception? Returns an unexpected value? Doesn't return for one reason or another? Unit testing should take these things into account.

Of course, if the base class call has no relevance to the method and how it works, then perhaps it shouldn't be called in that method at all. Some code refactoring may be required to fix this. This, in fact, is a huge benefit of unit testing as it can also help you with architectural issues such as this. Of course, assuming you are using `TDD` - rather than testing pre-written code - this can be a big help.

**Refactoring**

A potential way of refactoring this code is to not call the base class method in your overriden method. Have the base class ensure this method is called itself, and then in the overridden code call the code that is required. For instance:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public BuyerDeal Map(BuyerDealDTO buyerDealDTO, BuyerDeal buyerDealEntity)
    {
        // perform base class logic here

        var entity = this.MapInternal(buyerDealDTO, buyerDealEntity);

        return entity;
    }

    protected abstract BuyerDeal MapInternal(BuyerDealDTO buyerDealDTO, BuyerDeal buyerDealEntity);
}

public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    protected override BuyerDeal MapInternal(BuyerDealDTO buyerDealDTO, BuyerDeal buyerDealEntity)
    {            
        buyerDealEntity.prop1 = buyerDealDTO.prop2;
        return buyerDealEntity;
    }
}
```

Using this method, when you unit test `MyClass`, you are no longer testing `MyBaseClass::Map(...)` multiple times. Of course, you would still need to test `MyBaseClass` itself separately.

Comment: I do not agree that testing base class multiple times is a good idea, this is test code replication, which is generally bad. While `code coverage` is great, achieving this "accidentally" by testing base classes again is close to guessing as you do not monitor your coverage in a proper way then.

Comment: If the CUT uses a base class, then it should be tested in that situation. It is no different to a method calling a `private` method itself, when that `private` method is used often in other methods being tested.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I agree with that as base class is part of the CUT. I however disagree with your last paragraph that generalizes test code redundancy too much. When test coverage is monitored, then the base class test should typically already cover all paths. (Of course this might not always be possible)

Comment: " testing the base class multiple times, this is actually a very good thing" It's not different variation we talk about. you only maybe give different values which probably not result in different variation - you are testing the mapping here thats All .

Comment: You are also seeing how your method reacts to the base class call. As mentioned in the answer, if the method has no reaction at all, perhaps the call should be made elsewhere.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect how the call to the base class can be made elsewhere.